# Not able to do nested ssh using ssh_key in paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-keys

I am trying to nested SSH using paramiko where I will connect to system A and from there I will connect to system B. Here to connect to System A I am using username, password authentication and to connect to system B using username, ssh_key. The connection to System A is good but while trying to communicate to SystemB I am getting the error

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(sys_A, 22, user, password)
        print "Logged successfully to System A"
        #

        sshtransport = client.get_transport()
        dest_addr = (sys_B, 22)  # edited#
        local_addr = (sys_A, 22)  # edited#
        sshchannel = sshtransport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)
        #
        print "Logging to the node given"
        node_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        node_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/home/test_user/test/ssh_key')
        node_client.connect(sys_B, username='root', pkey=k, sock=sshchannel)

        print "Login successful to the node"
        #
        stdin, stdout, stderr = node_client.exec_command(cmd)  # edited#
        stdoutstr = ''
        stderrstr = ''
        for line in stdout.readlines():
            stdoutstr = stdoutstr + line + '\n'
        for line in stderr.readlines():
            stderrstr = stderrstr + line + '\n'
        return (stdoutstr, stderrstr)
```

And I am getting following error:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):     
  File "isolated_vm_test_base.py", line 173, in ssh_lpar_node_and_run_command
    k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/home/test_user/test/id_rsa')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 196, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 163, in _from_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key_file('RSA', filename, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 268, in _read_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key(tag, f, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 277, in _read_private_key
    raise SSHException('not a valid ' + tag + ' private key file')
SSHException: not a valid RSA private key file
```

here is how my private key looks like this

````
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----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#$KJXwcJ3iJM+DVgeSWCB+2FEVsNXhFXyg6gemLPPcsQqqKLxeZ1N9
e3Wew8xZUX3x/93J8xZTZ3ZLDo/MgEprJWFRMm2lJQhHvF+t6rTFXe6yWS68XOLTkelxBp
wFJnF3LfK7AZ5wd4MdmeN0DcyLVuKZR1A2WxIIcaKBEAxOI2WXJ7x6CvrDyQIVrLdIGBif
5J7d7oghU9l14/XqahOoryouS8ednC4yBB2IVqIAgLQsAPKGBoVzhHz9SE/z9tsjTxvvzI
rcjLQPtbwSJ/2OTFmqislL45ZQNoGHN6wdkzcFf6f0f5b06osLimIXlIGY6LVU0otp5u12
STtx8w+1569yKjXh$#FKUEDu2FK+SVf3rSSHA/3hGmU4X1ZwLcecvTRMZOM/e+tpN43p2k
q37w/6pWZEiy7+eVcYp53bhZFmhkztj53I0nd4B7oGS0d&IGGPiSkPra6ebJ9YVppClf1I
izKf5yWuL2HCuLKBQlYxuk+jQUANyRQqfb+qAgn4VF7+CdSrMKj18EnFMdwNlaxsMpDBl6
5nrAQnZC2B17v51oWahdymO0UsOLx/YZqjEzaWJ9XItmjp8TNJWS3wzLAvmnKH2FVYnUuO
MbdUDsH8+6gflaomHFAAABAQCBXxK2g6NN6111AGTVIYBFL/UrvYLGIgUivUNSrXdfPWHG
oSx1MgcgIzqPy/Zc6ECrW4mA3zzFzgWYMT4g3FEeGWhUu2kNO45mqsDLroTi/ZEKlNqABD
zjpOQVBYrOXw9WarJ7MmG0YTSLBJnXFAOOodWXKLElXVU&61QMUa1eQBmC4AHu5B7geySv
q+l4WBaABLUoFri3WNwZzc0yJ3Ds9y5Q/isM8h4w9J7Q/bhdp3L+ZXhXsrfQYr/u2sSpmy
sGo06FSfce6JqioSK8GkbnsNdncbzuPp8kw7Jy5lH/v6wWoHHGNeWEwprjBnSVCI2EDarN
CzcYY0xZ+EMzgIplAAABAQDyxOWAct90hHdd9bTOodZfhTrKDgS2pIR/KDhzjHwq0Ya3es
3Zws3CHCzjQ1YdWf32IneZpKMvQvxeJZsfwdCaQ3oRfyXhQFDgPSzxTDFCyyhQOBhbs5UQ
yFLIvay/40LBvn8GORCqvENfG4KMmUvj0wRt4fVdNzUouYZ0Lv8VhHwFjDCvgk2XmOhfS8
ArMS1o2J6xPz4dqXnqFpxwGxgjsKrt8W/ufzv3WDV0qx0pXgio7rmBoTZmhn4W9QEMyRbo
j/OqDSPUDL2x3xrZ9A6c6tBN4+o0a7REfAfPgaNQqEgwbniC3cPjcfj9SeeyR0b4F5xFE7
1PhJSHbaYVnHczAAABAQDbBsPnJfR/1MlMabHS4vN2hYL0AyxbYX36jluXdvdILmxa7S6w
wIURmFQwW4CWASLWBeEfj/bCCu7D8WWrKbskCNkUMVcTSFqMe7wHzwzGyZL2D8Gqja2YkA
td1r46inFC4u09imoHdyT0m7PirLVUBwbUd9kcAhnkAzr20WEeSFcMwm74hSVgQeCs9Ybh
SbFPYIOmkEWA24FQ0hUD62Kv9YPjH26I6jE/QB5IOwQh9UqVlBih3+SCM8aqOP8sITXL57
DQXzEBseRRp9b91nbBM+UxQhIU8YoJWOHYIAgT+b5TX/Z6dAeeSgpeaO9nSy7p2O08NCzo
AtQFxzK59W2TAAAAEXJvb3RAY2QxODE3ODM2YTE1AQ==
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----```
````

Comment: So will you tell us **anything** about your private key? -- Why do you even think your problem hast anything to do with *"nested SSH"*? You get an exception while calling an API that is not related to any specific connection.

Comment: I am not sure if this is problem with Nested ssh. Manually I am able to login to systemB using the same private key. My concern here is to make this code work, could you please help me out how I can make this work. I tried by providing the `key_filename` parameter as well. But that also didnot work.

Comment: Again, will you tell us **anything** about your private key? What kind of a key is that? What format? If you do not know, show us its structure. Or if you have generated the key, generate a new one (unregistered on the server), and post it here whole.

Comment: according to this post they asked me to generate new key with option like -p option. But I don't want to generate new key, want to use the exisiting key. How can I make this work. Your help is appriciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: Thaks the given link solves my problem

Comment: So please accept that your question is duplicate.